# How can I change a UIButton title/color without pressing the button in iOS?

Tags: ios, uibutton

The code below does everything I want it to (changing editButton title and color from normal color "Edit" to Red "Cancel" and back when depressed *except* that when the editButton displays Red "Cancel" and I press the sendButton, I would like the editButton to display normal color "Edit" again.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there something else I need to do?

Thanks,

John

```
- (IBAction)sendClicked:(id)sender {
    if (dontCheck) {
        dontCheck = NO;
        [editButton setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [editButton setTitleColor:[[sendButton titleLabel] textColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
    }
// ...     
}

- (IBAction)editClicked:(id)sender {
    if (dontCheck)  {
        dontCheck = NO;        
        dataLoaded = NO;
        [sender setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setTitleColor:[[submitButton titleLabel] textColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        dontCheck = YES;        
        [sender setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
// ...
}
```

This doesn't work for me: (I did make the necessary changes in the xib file.)

```
 - (IBAction)sendClicked:(id)sender { 
    if (dontCheck) {
        dontCheck = NO;
        [editButton setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [editButton setTitleColor:[[submitButton titleLabel] textColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [editButton setSelected:NO];
    }
  // ... 
}

 - (IBAction)editClicked:(id)sender { 
    if (dontCheck) { 
        dontCheck = NO; 
        dataLoaded = NO;
        [sender setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setTitleColor:[[submitButton titleLabel] textColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [editButton setSelected:NO`];
    } else {
        dontCheck = YES;
        [sender setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [sender setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [editButton setSelected:YES];
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: If my answered helped you, it is common courtesy on SO to mark the answer as accepted in order to let future readers know, that the answer is helpful.

Comment: That's what I thought. You will see that you are more likely to get responses if you mark answers accordingly as the percentage is displayed along with your badge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following addition did what I wanted (brought up to date in Swift):

```
@IBAction func editAction(_ sender: UIButton) 
{
        if (dontCheck) { 
            dontCheck = false 
            dataLoaded = false
            editButton.setTitle("Edit", for: [])
            editButton.setTitleColor(clearAllButton.tintColor, for: [])
            self.editButton.layer.borderColor =  clearAllButton.tintColor.cgColor
        }
        else
        {
            dontCheck = true        
            editButton.setTitle("Cancel", for: [])
            editButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: [])
            self.editButton.layer.borderColor =  UIColor.red.cgColor
        }
// ...
}
```

Adding the self.XXXButton.layer.borderColor equal to another, non-changing button's tintColor did the trick.

Answer (score 9):

You can set different colors for different states e.g. highlighted, selected, disabled. You would then not need to change the colors in the buttons target action. It would also allow you to simply call any of these methods to change the buttons state and appearance:

```
[editButton setDisabled:YES];
```

or

```
[editButton setSelected:YES];
```

To set colors for different states:

```
[editButton setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[editButton setTitleColor:[UIColor purpleColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[editButton setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[editButton setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still haven't been able to change the "Edit" button back from "Cancel" yet.